# Tracking incoming URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to change some CSS on a page based off the URL where the visitor came from.  I'm using a form to submit a value to a new page (a checkout page) which is hosted on a different server/site than where the form resides.  I have different forms sending this info over to the checkout page on 2 totally different sites.  On this checkout page, if the user comes from site A, I need to add a certain class to a div.  If the user comes over from site B, I need to add a different class to a div.  Something like this:

```
if incoming URL is equal to www.abc.com, then addClass ('classABC');

if incoming URL is equal to www.xyz.com, then addClass ('classABC');
```

Am I providing enough information to properly evaluate this?  Ideally I'd like to pull this off in jQuery but not sure if there's an existing plugin that can check this.  One thing to note, not all the forms being submitted to the checkout page reside on the same pages (i.e. www.xyz.com/index.html).  Some may be on different pages through each site, so I need to be able to figure this out based off the primary URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you pass the URL to the form as some kind of value or identifier?  Even `form.abc?from=1` versus `form.abc?from=2` or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to read the HTTP Refferer on the serverside. If you can then just put this value into a hidden input field like that `<input type="hidden" value="the referer" id="referer-value"/>` and read that hidden value for example using jquery like this `var referer = $('#referer-value').val();`. but as long as you can read the referer on the server you could also directly change the css file serverside.

Comment: Good advice.  Everyone has provided awesome answers, but for this particular situation, this solution will work perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Why in the world are you doing this on the client and not the server? You are already storing the value into the hidden filed, seems logical you would just add the class there. O_o

Comment: I'm using Foxy Cart ecommerce.  With the Foxy Cart "Add to Cart" form, the user adds a product to the cart (AJAX form) and in the form is a hidden input field where we define a category based on the site they are on.  For example, if they're on the "www.abc.com" site, then we'll assign a category of "abc".  When the form is submitted, the info is sent to the Foxy Cart checkout page and info from the form is stored in JSON.  In this case, site "www.abc.com" will have category of "abc".  With JSON, I can write a simple jQuery to check the JSON and act accordingly.

Comment: FYI, HTTP referrer is a very bad way to get anything.  Not only is it not secure, it's also not always supported.  Using HTTP referrer is a poor choice in many ways, but using it in a shopping cart is just foolhardy.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in JavaScript/jQuery you'll need to either add a URL parameter to the page to indicate which site it's from or use server-side code to embed the css in the page (which would be better).  On the server you could do it with http referrer, but it's not 100% reliable so is still better to use a url parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch(location.hostname) {
   case 'www.xyz.com': 
   case 'xyz.com':
      $('div#yourid').addClass('classXYZ'); break;
   case 'www.abc.com':
   case 'abc.com': 
      $('div#yourid').addClass('classABC'); break;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `location.hostname` refers to the current host, not the referring host.

Comment: oh, sorry... overseen that in question

Comment: actually if the code is inside a .js file and you for example provide an API through that .js file and other webdeveloper use that .js file than this approach is pretty usefull!

Comment: @ITroubs well, you'd have to define somehow the `{site: class}` mapping first to call this an API ;)